# Scope of functions /objects

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I would have thought that `console.log(myCounting.value);` would actually print `7` because the add method got invoked twice (see comments) . However it prints `6`. Is that because of the scope? Meaning that invoking the 'invoking' function with `myCounting.add` doesn't change the value because its a different scope? Could someone explain as I'm learning scopes..Thanks!!

```
function Counting(){
  this.value = 5;
}

Counting.prototype.add = function(){
  this.value++;
}

var myCounting = new Counting();
myCounting.add();   // invoked once

function invoking(funcs){
  funcs();
}

invoking(myCounting.add); //invoked twice
console.log(myCounting.value);
```

Comment: try `invoking(myCounting.add.bind(myCounting));`

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't really have that much to do with scope (except that functions create scope maybe?). It has everything to do with how `this` works.

The value of `this` depends on **how the function is called**. There are a handful of ways a function could be called, each can result in a different value for `this`. In your example, `myCounting.add()` and `func()` are different ways of calling a function, resulting in different values for `this`, and hence `this.value++` will be applied to two different objects.

See [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/218196) and maybe [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196) for more information.

Comment: Thank you. As I understand, this refers the caller. How then in this following example, this does NOT refer to the object? var name="j";
var myObject={
 name:"x",
 property:{
  name:"y",
  getFull:function(){
   return this.name;
  }
 }
};
var fullname=myObject.property.getFull;
fullname();

Comment: *"As I understand, this refers the caller."* That's not correct (but I guess that depends on what you mean by "caller"). Only a function can be the caller of another function. In that sense, `this` doesn't refer to the caller. The reason why `this` doesn't refer to the object in your other example is that you are calling the function as `fullname()`. When a function is called this way, `this` refers to the global object or is `undefined` in strict mode. How the function was defined doesn't matter. Functions are first class citizens in JavaScript and they are not automatically bound.

Comment: `this` refers to the object to the left of the last dot that's to the left of the method name, like _y_ in `x.y.z()`. if there is nothing to the left, then it's the same as _window_:`window.y()`'s `this` == `y()`'s `this`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, in Javascript the value of `this` evaluates differently depending on how/where the function is called:

In your first example:

```
myCounting.add()
```

`this` refers to the calling object of the `add` function, which in this case is your `myCounting` instance, as you expect.

In your second example:

```
invoking(myCounting.add)
```

Here, `add` is bound to the top-level `window` object (if called from within a browser) since it's being called from the top-level scope. Accordingly, `this` is actually the global window object.

The result is the same as if you called `this.value++` directly from your browser console. Since `this.value` is `undefined` the result of `this.value++` is (nonsensically) `NaN`.

Comment: "*add is treated like a globally declared function and bound to the top-level window object* no it's not. Its *this* is set to the global object because it was not set by the call. Where the object was created or called from is irrelevant (except for arrow functions), *this* is set by how the function is called (or use of *bind*).

Comment: This is more of a semantic distinction, though I agree the wording here can be construed to make it seem like the value of `this` depends on where the function is defined, which is not generally the case. I've updated my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: The second last paragraph is still misleading.